# Data model for Item made of Materials (that are also an item) in an inventory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building the Crafting mechanics into my game in unity and my data model has run into a hitch:

I want every "Item" in my game to be made of a "ResourceMaterial"
I also want ReseourceMaterial to inherit from Item

It is important that ResourceMaterial inherits from Item because Item is used in all the code for being able to be picked up, added to, and manipulated in the inventory.

The problem is every Item has a list of ResourceMaterials that are Items and therefore have a list of ResourceMaterials that are Items that have a list of ResourceMaterials etc... forever.

How do I restructure this to avoid the forever issue?

```cs
//Here is an example of the classes
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID;          //from db
    public string Name;         //items name
    public string Description;  //A description of the items uses

    //...//

    public List<ResourceMaterial> ResourceMaterials = new List<ResourceMaterial>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ResourceMaterial : Item
{
    public int ResourceID;      //from db
    public int NumberRequired;  
    public int WorkingTime;     //time in seconds to use
}
```

Comment: Why not have the list contain `ResourceID` instead of `ResourceMaterial`?

Comment: I thought of that too, but it still gives me a Serialization depth limit 7 exceeded error EDIT: stand by, the error might be unrelated

Comment: Weird, that should not happen as all it is, is a list of ints.

Comment: If you dont do the  "= new List<ResourceMaterial>();" it should be fine.

Comment: @Iggy you are right, a list of ints works without serialization issues.

Comment: @CaptainNoah classic problem when dealing with serialization and databases, everything needs an ID.

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez that makes sense, since the ResourceMaterial Item would not be creating a new list of ResourceMaterials, but it still gives the "Serialization depth limit" warning

Comment: Decided to have a list of ResourceIDs and a dictionary of all Resources. That should make everything work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Don't serialize the `Item` instances, serialize `ItemStack`s

The only thing you need to serialized about an `Item` its its ID. That's it. They're already automatically constructed when the game starts, you don't need to save their structure to disk.

When you deserialize a stack you look up the `Item` instance that already exists by ID and point the stack at it.

You're probably going to have to use a more detailed serialization system than JsonUtiliy, such as JSON .NET, so that you can write the custom contract resolver and custom converters that will be needed.

Additionally you probably shouldn't keep the recipe for how to create an item *in the Item class.* Use a recipe manager that holds onto your recipes. This allows for far more flexibility.